# Show subcat from Cat by using php & ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i need to show the sub cat from selecting cat by using ajax and php

first select cat

```
 <select style="font-family:'Droid Arabic Kufi', serif"  id='dep' name="dep_id" class="form-control m-bot15">
                       <option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>
                       <?php
                       $e = mysql_query("select * from dep");
                       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($e)) {
                       extract($row);
                       echo"<option value='$id'>$dep_name</option>";
                       }
                       ?>
                       </select>
```

2- Show SubCat From first step

```
 <select id='subdep' name="subdep_id" class="form-control m-bot15">
                <option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>
                </select> 
                <script>
                $('#dep').change(function(){
                var ob;
                var t = this;
                depid = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                url: 'combo.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: "q=1&id=" + depid,
                success: function(result) {
                ob = $.parseJSON(result);
                $('#subdep').empty().append("<option value='' hidden selected='selected'></option>");
                for (i = 0; i < ob[0].length; i++) {
                $('#subdep').append($('<option>', {
                value: ob[0][i],
                text: ob[1][i]
                }));
                }
                }
                });
                });
                </script>
```

3- the process file combo.php

```
include("config.php");
```

if (isset($_POST)) {
    $q = $_POST['q'];

```
if ($q == '1') {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $arr = array(array(array()));
    $e = mysql_query("select * from sub where dep='" . $id . "'") or die('sql error');
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($e)) {
        $arr[0][$i] = $row['id'];
        $arr[1][$i++] = $row['sub_name'];
    }
    $json = json_encode($arr);
    print_r($json);
}
```

it not working i need to know Why ?